# Kafka-connect add more topics on the fly

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have an [elasticsearch `kafka-connect` connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html) consuming some topics.
With the following configuration:

```
{
    connection.url": "https://my-es-cluster:443",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "topics": "topic1,topic2",
    ...
}
```

Can I **add more topics** to it while it's running?
What will happen?
What if I **remove some topics** from list and **add them again** later.

I'd like to add a new `topic3` here:

```
{
    ...
    "topics": "topic1,topic2,topic3",
    ...
}
```

What is I remove `topic2`? Will other topics be re-consumed?:

```
{
    ...
    "topics": "topic1,topic3",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have your `kafka` and `kafka-connect` running, you can use REST API of `kafka-connect` and check that yourself: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html

If you add a new topic (`topic3`), all messages currently in that topic (according to retention policy) will be consumed.

```
PUT http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/my-test-connector/config
{
   ...
   "topics": "topic1,topic2,topic3",
   ...
}
```

Check status and config of this connector:

```
GET http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/my-test-connector
```

If you want to disable some topic, just use `PUT` to update config for that connector.

```
PUT http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/my-test-connector/config
{
   ...
   "topics": "topic1,topic3",
   ...
}
```

Nothing will change for `topic1` and `topic3`. Just `topic2` will not be consumed any more.
But if you want to return it back, messages from `topic2` will be consumed from the last committed offset, and not from beginning.

For each `consumer group` last committed `offset` is stored, does not matter that you removed topic from the config for a while. 
For this case, the consumer group will be `connect-my-test-connector`.

Even is you delete the connector (`DELETE http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/my-test-connector`) and then create it again with the same name, the offset will be saved, and consumption will be continued from them point when you've deleted it. (mind the retention policy, it's usually 7 days).

Comment: Does rebalance happen when we add a new topic or remove the topic?